# Spark Sql query is taking longer time in scala

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hql

I am new to Spark sql, I have a spark sql query running inside a for loop. Example,

```
val sQuery = "select distinct col1, col2, col3 from HiveDB.HiveTableName"
```

The query is being executed sequentially for different hive db and table in the loop, almost 200 db and tables. There is a performance hit because the query has to run for entire tables. I tried to rewrite/optimize the query like

```
val sQuery = "select * from (select col1, col2, col3, dense_rank() over (order by `date` desc) as rnk  from HiveDB.HiveTableName ) b where b.rnk =1"
```

But still I see it is taking same time as compared to first query. Can anyone suggest to optimize the query.

Spark version used 2.3.2
Tables are external ORC format and it is partitioned by yyyy-mm.

Comment: just curious, what are you trying to do by reading all the tables from multiple db's in one go

Comment: Nikunj, I am reading tables sequentially inside the for loop. After processing I am writing the result to another hive table.

Comment: @Shree you haven't specified the partition in your original query, that's why it scans the entire table. Is it part of the requirement where you have to read without partitions?